# OS X 10.9 Screen Sharing: disable file transfer

Tags: macos, security, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

> On OS X 10.7 or newer (10.8, 10.9) simply drag'n'drop files between
>   your desktop and remote desktop to transfer the files between
>   computers

How can I disable this?
I have made restricted account just for Screen Sharing, and I don't want remote user to be able to copy files from my machine without any serious effort.

Comment: When you say "I have restricted account just for Screen Sharing" do you mean you set up a separate account that you use for screen sharing only? And: are you aware that someone else controlling the session with screen sharing can copy files over the remote system anyway, even if not with drag&drop (since they are *controlling* the computer)?

Comment: I've set up a restricted account (OS X call this "managed account"). This user can't run/install any app or access any site except those that I whitelisted for him. He can't copy files out of this system easily

Comment: Well if you go through that much hassle anyway you might as well run your own VNC server or TeamViewer which allows more control. Seems like a curious use-case anyway ;-)

Comment: This is not how SSharing works. But you can disable access to specific folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove Screen Sharing server's helper tools from here:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/screensharingd.bundle/Contents/Support/*
```

Quick check didn't show anything bad for the rest of server functions.

Please note that after an OS X update these helpers might be resurrected.