# Unable to delete a folder to disable drag and drop, during screen-sharing

Tags: terminal, mojave, macos

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/136038/9058) claims

> You can just remove Screen Sharing server's helper tools from here:
> `/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/screensharingd.bundle/Contents/Support/`
>
> Quick check didn't show anything bad for the rest of server functions.

I am trying to delete the /Support folder but, I get "operation not permitted". I am in as root and have tried to sudo chown, chmod, mv, rm -Rrf, etc. The only command that worked for me was cp -rv.. Any idea what the issue is?

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   128 Mar 28  2019 Support
```

Comment: You have SIP enabled I assume?

Comment: Correct, do I have to disable this function before I delete the folder?..